# Send message back to mainthread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I made an app that checks available RAM in my samsung-device. I want the value to be updated every two seconds.

I put this in a background-thread and I don't know how to send the calculated value back to the main thread. I guess I handler-class is necessary but don't know how to implement it

```
private TextView tv;
private Handler handler;
private long availableMegs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meminfo_view);
    tv.setText("TILLGÄNGLIGT RAM = " + availableMegs);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

                tv.setText("TILLGÄNGLIGT RAM = " + availableMegs);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }

    });

    t.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to get synchronized with the UI Thread would be:

```
tv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("TILLGÄNGLIGT RAM = " + availableMegs);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would suggest to take a `Listener` based approach. You might want to create an interface:

```
public interface OnMemoryListener{

    public void onMemoryReceived(String value);
}
```

Create a separate class extending `Thread` in order to keep the code clean:

```
public static class MemoryThread extends Thread{

    private OnMemoryListener listener;

    public MemoryThread(OnMemoryListener l){
        super();
        listener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // execute memory code

        if(listener != null)
            listener.onMemoryReceived(value);
         try {
             Thread.sleep(2000);
         } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
             //...
         }          
         super.run();
    }

}
```

Make your activity implement the `OnMemoryListener` and provide the necessary code for handling the result. If you want to run the listener's code on the main thread you can use activitiy's `runOnUiThread()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  MemoryThread mt = new MemoryThread(this);
  mt.start();
}

@Override
public void onMemoryReceived(final String value){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // handle the result here

            }
        });
}
```